# Stream GroupBy List<List<String>>

Tags: java, java-stream

Admitting I have these data:

```
List<String> headers = List.of("name", "age");
List<List<String>> rows = List.of(List.of("Joe", "30"), List.of("Mike", "40"));
```

The "headers" can contain more than two elements, but the size of each list in "rows" will always be the same as "headers".

I want to produce the following result using the Stream API as a List<Map<String, String>>:

```
[
 ( "name" -> "Joe", "age" -> "30"),
 ( "name" -> "Mike", "age" -> "40")
]
```

How can I achieve that, is it possible without nesting loop ?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: No, it's not possible without nesting a loop. What have you tried so far to solve your problem?

Comment: Yes it is possible.  A nested loop requires two loops, an inner one and an outer one.  You can do this with a single iteration within a stream.

Comment: @WJS you can't - you will have to iterate `rows` first, then you will have to iterate over `headers` and also potentially over each individual `row`. Streams aren't magic, they are just a fancy way to express some algorithms and maybe cut down on boilerplate a little bit. But the algorithm which forms this particular output from this particular input can't require less than an outer loop and a nested internal loop.

Comment: Show me the explicit inner loop in the accepted solution (and not the ones behind the scenes).  I only see one that could be considered a loop is `IntStream.range().`  And streams are not there to cut down on boilerplate or just fancy ways of doing something.  They allow pipe-lining objects to avoid duplicate data structures thus reducing overhead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be something like this:

```java
List<Map<String, String>> result = rows.stream()
    .map(row -> IntStream.range(0, headers.size())
        .mapToObj(i -> Map.entry(headers.get(i), row.get(i)))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue)))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

What this does, is the following. It streams over the rows, and maps each element of the row (which is a `List<String>`) to a `Map<String, String>` The keys are taken from `headers`, and the values from the list. In order to map the *n*th header to the *n*th value of the sublist, we use an `IntStream` with the indexes. This of course assumes that each sublist's length is equal to the length of `headers`.

However, this is still *effectively* a nested loop<sup>1</sup>. One must eventually visit each element of each sublist, so this cannot really be done without a nested loop. However, the loop itself is abstracted away.

---

<sup>1</sup> It depends on what you call a 'loop', of course. The two loops used here are `Stream::collect` and `IntStream::range`. And, as M. Prokhorov mentioned in the comments, some implementations of `List::get` could also use a loop, for example `LinkedList`.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Stream API so thank you for taking the time to help me and not just downvote :)

Comment: I don't like it. Using iterators here seems like a better solution.

Comment: Actually, imo, this is not a nested loop  (which requires two loops, an inner and an outer).  You are only using one IntStream to pull the headers.  If that is a nested loop, then most solutions of streams would be considered a nested loop.

Comment: @WJS, yes and no. `rows.stream()..collect()` is a loop, and so is `range..collect`. Then, depending on implementation of composing lists, `List::get` can also a be loop from `0` to `i`.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov Then that would mean the doing anything with a stream is using a loop which is clearly not what the OP meant.

Comment: @WJS, not quite anything with a stream, but anything in this particular type of stream. Collection streams all have an iterator as their head stage. And, as I already said, it's not possible to transform these lists into a list of maps without nested loops. Streams aren't magic, there's going to be a loop in it somewhere. The difference here is usually with streams developer doesn't write `for (...)` or `while()` by hand, he only provides the body of the loop.

Comment: Or ...`IntStream.range(0, headers.size()).boxed().collect(Collectors.toMap(i -> headers.get(i), i -> row.get(i)))`  (though autoboxing overhead)

Comment: @Eklavya-UpvoteDon'tSayThanks That's another option indeed. This can be further shortened to `IntStream.range(0, headers.size()).boxed().collect(Collectors.toMap(headers::get, row::get))`.